# Change a template Chapter Layout

Tags: layout

I am using this Overleaf template provided in [template link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-rochester-masters-slash-phd-thesis-template/bwkpcxzdysky)

They given:

[image]

I want to change to this `chapter` layout:

[image]

Is it possible?
I cannot find out where they do the setting for this.

They main.tex file:

```
\begin{document}

% Title page
\include{structure/title}

% All subsequent pages must be numbered, title page is considered page i,
% front matter is numbered in lowercase Roman numerals
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\doublespacing

% Dedication (optional)
\include{structure/dedication}

% Acknowledgments
\include{structure/acknowledgements}

% Abstract
\include{structure/abstract}

% Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures
\tableofcontents

%List of Tables & Figures
\include{structure/tablesfigures}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DISSERTATION CONTENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Regular numbering starts now, first page of first chapter is page 1
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% Body


\include{chapters/01-introduction}

\include{chapters/02-background}

\include{chapters/03-chapter}

\include{chapters/04-chapter}

% References
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}{}
\singlespacing
\printbibliography

\appendix
\include{chapters/99-appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it will be next-to-impossible for others to compile your document since it has `\include{structure/title}` and many more `\include`s of files that most of us won't have. But you can get any layout of the chapter headings with the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this but maybe

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\Huge}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Study 1: Study about \LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

[image]

gives you what you want. As I wrote in the comment, it is impossible to test this in your document, so all I did is to get the class from the link, and to use it in the answer.

Comment: cat. Thanks a lot. It really works well. I just put your code in different tex. `main.tex` and `chapter.text` Really work well. Thanks!

Comment: @aan You're welcome! Please consider for the future to add codes that everyone can compile, Then several users will upvote them because they are useful for many. Thanks! ;-)

Comment: cat. Noted. Because the template have several file in different location. I will try make it in one file. Secondly. can I ask how to change the `font size`? The `20pt` in `{\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\Huge}` is the `font size`. Can i have like `Chapter 1` bigger size, and `Study 1:xxx` smaller size?

Comment: @aan `\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\Large}`. In this modified version, `\Huge` controls the size of `Chapter 1` and `\Large` the size of the rest.

Comment: cat. Thanks! Brilliant. Thanks once again